# Twilio - Automated testing on VMWare

Tags: selenium, twilio, vmware

We are developing a Twilio based web application (AngularJS and Microsoft WebAPI) and have assembled a number of automated tests using SpecFlow, Selenium Webdriver and Chromedriver. We use the Programmable Voice component to make calls and the automated tests make calls to test numbers. The tests all run fine on developer machines, but when deployed on Windows 2012R2 Datacenter virtual machines running on VMWare VSphere/ESXi 6 hosts they fail as Chromedriver cannot find a recording device so therefore won't establish the WebRTC connection to Twilio. The hosts that we use do not have a sound card and therefore show no audio devices available to the VMs. I believe we can add a USB sound card to the host and share it with one VM, but this is a clunky solution that renders VMWare DRS a bit useless and we have several VMs that we'd like to run these tests on. I'm hoping I'm not the first person to try to use automated testing with Twilio so was looking for how others had implemented it in a virtual/cloud environment? I have raised a support case with Twilio but they had no ideas.

Comment: There are a number of different "virtual audio device" drivers available that might give you what you need.  This is one:  http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm  caveat: I've not actually done this in a virtualized cloud environment so this may or may not work.

Comment: Quick update.  Found out that both Chrome and FF have switches built in to allow you to mock audio devices: https://blog.andyet.com/2014/09/29/testing-webrtc-applications/

Comment: Thanks Devin, but I've never managed to get those Virtual Audio Devices to work in our environment. They install but never present any devices to Windows. My theory is that it is due to a lack of sound card presented to the VM, I think these devices still require a sound card. I'm having a USB external sound card added to one of the hosts tomorrow that I will present to one VM so I'll soon find out.

Comment: I had seen some switches for Chrome, but not that one. I'll give it a bash.

Comment: Devin - you're a star, the Chrome switch --use-fake-ui-for-media-stream works a treat and also works with chromedriver. I have successfully made Twilio calls on a VM with no sound card, thank you. As an aside, I also installed a USB sound card (https://www.startech.com/uk/Cards-Adapters/Sound/USB-Audio/Audio-USB-Adapter~ICUSBAUDIOB) and could share that with one VMWare VM.  This also worked, but is very limited as per my original post so your solution is much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Devin Rader provided the answer. blog.andyet.com/2014/09/29/testing-webrtc-applications explains how to add a switch to Chrome (--use-fake-device-for-media-stream) that fakes a microphone and means that you can make a WebRTC connection in Chrome without a microphone device. There is also a switch for Firefox that I assume works but I haven't tried it. The switch also works with Chromedriver and I have successfully run Selenium tests using Chromedriver on a Windows 2012R2 server VM with no sound card. Thanks Devin.

Comment: Mozilla added the ability to set fake audio devices as a profile option in the meantime. You might want to take a look at https://github.com/webrtc/adapter/blob/master/test/selenium-lib.js#L48 which contains some newer techniques than shown in my old blog post.